# SML: Function composition with isSome

Tags: sml, smlnj, function-composition

I have the following examples and they do not work even though the types do matchup with each other

```
- isSome;
val it = fn : 'a option -> bool


- SOME;
val it = fn : 'a -> 'a option
- val my_converter = (fn x => if x = 5 then SOME x else NONE);
val my_converter = fn : int -> int option
```

Both SOME and my_converter return an option but when I do the following

```
- fn x => isSome o SOME x;
stdIn:19.9-19.24 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: ('Z option -> bool) * ('Y -> 'Z option)
  operand:         ('Z option -> bool) * 'X option
  in expression:
    isSome o SOME x
```

I get a type error why?

Comment: Since `isSome o SOME` returns `true` for all input, I don't see the motivation of ever using it.

Comment: That is the simplest example of builtins I can use to demonstrate a more general pattern of how do you combine isSome with a conditional based SOME/NONE pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `o` wants a function operand but what it actually gets is an `option`. This is because `isSome o SOME x` parses as `isSome o (SOME x)`, which makes no sense.

You can fix this by writing

```
(isSome o SOME) x
```

instead.